# Цвет шрифта во всех ячейках datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Необходимо изменять цвет шрифта в ячейках при обновлении данных в `datagridview`. Вот код:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gridShift.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(gridShift.Rows[i].Cells["planned"].Value) == 1)
                gridShift.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(gridShift.Rows[i].Cells["ErrUpload"].Value) == 1)
            {
                gridShift.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                gridShift.Rows[i].Cells[].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
//Как указать все ячейки без цикла
            }
        }
```

Как изменить цвет шрифта во всех ячейках строки?

Comment: Верно понимаю, что нужно поменять цвет именно шрифта именно во в какой-то определенной строке (т.е. как бы "выделить" строку)?

Comment: @BlackWitcher, разобрался, если вы заметили то я циклом крашу в красный цвет строки по условию, из за красного цвета плохо видно шрифт, по этому хотел перекрасить в белый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему методом тыка так :

```
gridShift.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: Отлично, что решение нашлось.